# Randomise colour of gMap routes

Tags: c#, google-maps

How would I randomise the colour of `r.Stroke.Color` for every route generated?

```
            var myFile = new CsvFile(@".\netting.csv");
            for (int row = 1; row < myFile.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < myFile.Rows[row].Fields.Count; col++)
                {
                    var markersOverlay = new GMapOverlay("markers");
                    var startMarker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(Convert.ToDouble(myFile.Rows[row].Fields[3]), Convert.ToDouble(myFile.Rows[row].Fields[4])), GMarkerGoogleType.green_dot);
                    var goalMarker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(Convert.ToDouble(myFile.Rows[row].Fields[5]), Convert.ToDouble(myFile.Rows[row].Fields[6])), GMarkerGoogleType.red_dot);             
                    markersOverlay.Markers.Add(startMarker);
                    markersOverlay.Markers.Add(goalMarker);
                    gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(markersOverlay);

                    var start = new PointLatLng(Convert.ToDouble(myFile.Rows[row].Fields[3]), Convert.ToDouble(myFile.Rows[row].Fields[4]));
                    var end = new PointLatLng(Convert.ToDouble(myFile.Rows[row].Fields[5]), Convert.ToDouble(myFile.Rows[row].Fields[6]));
                    var route = GoogleMapProvider.Instance.GetRoute(start, end, false, false, 15);
                    var r = new GMapRoute(route.Points, "My route");
                    r.Stroke.Width = 2;
                    r.Stroke.Color = Color.SeaGreen;
                    var routesOverlay = new GMapOverlay("routes");
                    routesOverlay.Routes.Add(r);
                    gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(routesOverlay);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a random color method like

```
Color randomColor(){
        System.Random rdm = new Random();
        int red = rdm.Next(0,255);
        int green = rdm.Next(0,255);
        int blue = rdm.Next(0,255);

        return Color.FromArgb(red,green,blue);

    }
```

then you could assign that color to your route:

```
route.Stroke = new Pen(randomColor(),3);
```